# Insert Custom Channel Field Grid into Database?

Tags: module, grid, fieldtype

Is there a better way to tie into EE to create a grid field? During my module install, I am having it setup a new grid field to relate to a custom channel field group that setups up the required table information for a grid in my database. Example below. I feel there has to be a better/cleaner way to achieve this.

```
    // Create exp_channel_fields and assign by group_id
    ee()->db->insert(

        'exp_channel_fields',
            array(

                'site_id'               => 1,
                'group_id'              => 0,
                'field_name'            => 'menu',
                'field_label'           => 'Sidebar Nav',
                'field_instructions'    => 'Add links to display on sidebar nav.',
                'field_type'            => 'grid',
                'field_pre_populate'    => 0,
                'field_pre_channel_id'  => 0,
                'field_pre_field_id'    => 0,
                'field_ta_rows'         => 6,
                'field_maxl'            => 128,
                'field_required'        => 'n',
                'field_text_direction'  => 'ltr',
                'field_search'          => 'n',
                'field_is_hidden'       => 'n',
                'field_fmt'             => 'xhtml',
                'field_show_fmt'        => 'n',
                'field_order'           => 3,
                'field_content_type'    => 'any',
                'field_settings'        => $field_settings

            )
    );



    ee()->db->insert(

        'exp_grid_columns',
            array(

                'field_id'         => $exp_channel_field_id,
                'content_type'     => 'channel',
                'col_order'        => 0,
                'col_type'         => 'multi_select',
                'col_label'        => 'Nav Select',
                'col_name'         => 'nav_option',
                'col_required'     => 'n',
                'col_search'       => 'n',
                'col_width'        => 0,
                'col_settings'     => '{"field_fmt":"none","field_list_items":"link1\nlink2\nlink3","field_required":"n"}'

            )

    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best approach to this was to tie directly into Expression Engine's Channel fields API.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_fields.html#fetch-all-fieldtypes